# Hash en Angular

Tags: html, angular, hash, href, angular10

Tengo una pequeña duda, a la hora de clickear un anchor que togglee un elemento, no me hace ningún efecto...

Ejm, tengo lo sgte:

```
<a href="#menu">Menu</a>
```

Y tengo el respectivo elemento que se debe Togglear al darle clic en el anchor anterior:

```
<div id="menu">...</div>
```

El problema es que no funciona a la hora de darle click en el anchor...

Los dos elementos están en **Componentes** distintos... el anchor está en el header, y el div está en otro componente diferente.

¿Qué podría estar sucediendo?

(Estoy con la versión 10 de Angular)

Answer (score 0):

```
.component.ts
function getIndex($id){
 return (
  this.removeIndex($id)
    alert("This element was removed")
  )
}
.html
<form id="form" method="post">
<input  id="{this.accesors.id}">
 <input type="submit" 
callbackforApplySend...getIndex({this.accesors.id}) 
name="sendendform" value="removeIndex" >
</form>
```

en este ejemplo puedes ver como funciona un callback para remover un elemento y acceder a la función, debes llamarlo desde un componente donde se hace render del dom donde esta se esta haciendo la llamada a dicho dom.

este es un ejemplo de toggle, si lo que querias es togglear desde un anchor

```
app.component.html
  <button (click)=toggleDisplayDiv() >Toggle display Div</button>
  <div [hidden]="isShowDiv">Div.</div>

 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
 export class AppComponent {
 title = 'appComponent';

 isShowDiv = false;

toggleDisplayDiv() {
 this.isShowDiv = !this.isShowDiv;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia Kinslert.
Parece que el código no me funciona con la función toggle que le deseo hacer al elemento `<div>` ... No es que esté trayendo datos dinámicamente de una BD, sólo necesito es Togglear un elemento por medio de un anchor.

Comment: seguramente esto te funcionará.

Comment: Muchas gracias Kin!
Intenté con el nuevo código, pero me marca error en la propiedad **isShowDiv**.. tanto en el html como en el ts..
Tengo el html del div en un Componente aparte, y el html del anchor y el ts del mismo en otro componente aparte.. ¿Crees que pueda ser por eso?.. ¿hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Comment: Para poder hacer uso de los componentes ambos deben estar importados en el app.module, sea bien el modulo creado por la misma sección del compononente en el app deben estar los 2 y luego si vas a hacer uso de alguno fuera del componente principal puedes hacer el llamado de un componente en el modulo extra.

Te sugiero que lo hagas con un contenedor como stackblitz.